# How to write unittest for function that accepts csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

My function looks like this

```
import pandas as pd 

def my_function( file_path ):
    df = pd.read_csv( filepath )
    #some other operations on df here 
    return df
```

I do not want to access an external file for unit test. Is there any way to create a csv file like object on the fly for unit testing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520279/python-unit-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think it would be better to re-write your function so that it accepts a `DataFrame`, does some calculation on that `DataFrame`, and returns the `DataFrame`. In this sense you have made your function more atomic, it only manipulates the DataFrame as opposed to loading data **and** manipulating data. For this, you'd then create a test DataFrame and check the output. You can look at [how pandas implements tests](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/tests/internals/test_internals.py) to get some inspiration

If you don't care for that, then we can make use of the flexibility of `pd.read_csv` and pass it a `_io.StringIO` object which it will parse into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def my_function(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    return df 

file_path = StringIO('col1,col2,col3\n1,2,3\n4,5,6')

df = my_function(file_path)
print(df)
#   col1  col2  col3
#0     1     2     3
#1     4     5     6
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes you are right. I have to refactor my code.